# Blazor WebAssembly redirect issue (to Identity Server) using custom router

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor-webassembly

I'am currently trying to integrate an alternative Router for Blazor WASM which is capable of showing the current culture by re-writing the URL. For this, I use the [Router from Ant Design](https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/tree/master/site/AntDesign.Docs/Routing).
In general it works, BUT it gets tricky when using [identity server authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and its redirect mechanism.
When the user isn't authenticated, he/she's redirected to the identity server, but by using these chopped and re-constructed URL's the redirect gets disrupted.

Thus, I added a **navigateTo** for unauthenticated users (which is the same as in the **RedirectToLogin** component) to intercept the re-writting and using the default URL without culture for the authentication redirect.

```
// ConventionRouter.cs

 private async Task RefreshAsync()
 {
     var relativeUri = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(_location);
     var hash = string.Empty;
     var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;

     if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         // this redirect is run before any URL changes are made.
         Dispose();
         NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(_location)}");
         return;
     }            
...
```

This kinda works, but the redirect never reaches the ASP .NET MVC login methods and remains
on "localhost:5001/authentication/login?returnUrl={redirectURL}". It's not my first attempt on changing the routing behaviour but thus far I failed, also because I'am not able to debug what's going on inside the default Router when being redirected to the identity server.

**My question**: Does anybody know how the routing to the API's identity server (*the redirect from **authentication/login** to **/Identity/Account/Login** served by the API*) works in detail and how I can change its behaviour? Is this issue maybe related to the routers context or is it even missing important functionality which the [default router](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Components/Components/src/Routing/Router.cs) contains?

```
// App.razor - To show the router is integrated in the app's structure

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <ConventionRouter AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Common.Components.Layouts.Main.Layout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (context.User.Identity != null && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Common.Components.Layouts.Main.Layout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </ConventionRouter>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>


<AntDesign.AntContainer />
```

As a workaround I intended to directly navigate to the "localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login", which seems to work but also appears to be hacky.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Do you mean that the redirect URL will only take effect if it is hard-coded?

Comment: When using the custom router from Ant Design, yes. Or at least, this is the only way we found so far. I should maybe add, that the redirect for authentication is triggered automatically when accessing the website.